# Import labels into QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

In ArcGIS, when I want to Label my layer, there are a number of label styles I can choose from.

I would like to have that Feature in QGIS as well. For example, when I label my layer in a certain font, color, format and buffer, I would like to save my self-made label and just add it to another layer. Would that be possible?

Comment: At the bottom left of the style window is the corresponding menu. Styles have to be in .qml-format.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I thought .qml-format represents only symbology but it does also store label styles.

Comment: .qml stores almost everything, sadly not layernames, but also predefined values etc.

Answer (score 3):

To copy label style from one layer to another, right click on the layer name in the layer panel (the "table of contents" or "ToC" as Arc-users like to call it) > Styles > Copy/Paste Style > Labels

[image]

Note: In QGIS 2, it was only possible to copy/paste all the style settings at once. The ability to copy/paste parts of the style (like label settings) is a new feature in QGIS 3.